# Boot menu, laptop

Tags: boot

Boot menu is displayed when I woke up  the laptop. OS is already installed. Laptop is lenovo

[image]

What should I do next? I want the laptop to start normally

Answer (score 1):

Does it boot when you choose the hard drive?

This would suggest the Bios cannot find an operating system. If you are sure you installed an OS to the hard drive, it might have a broken boot sector or broken hard drive. It might also be the case that you enabled or disabled secure boot after or before installing an OS.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet. I'm not sure whether to press **esc** or to select **anything else**

Comment: I would first try to Enter(Select) the currently highlighted ATA HDD(hard drive) option. Presumably you installed the OS to the hard drive. If that does not boot the machine or gets you straight back into this menu, one of the issues I described in my answer is probably present.

Comment: It gets me back to the same menu. What happens if I press **esc**? Can I restart by "press and hold"ing the power button?

Comment: That means no operating system can be found. Pressing esc might bring you to the bios or might restart the computer. You can indeed press and hold to shut down, but that won't fix your problem.

Comment: Your drive is a five year old design https://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/11224/WDC-WD10JPCX-24UE4T0 and failure on a consumer drive of that vintage is not surprising. Which Lenovo model do you have? Please get the model number off the serial number sticker, click [edit], and update the question with that information. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Pressing **esc** brings me back to the same menu, so does **selecting HDD and restarting**. I'm not sure what could have caused this to happen.

Comment: You could just be out of luck with your hard drive and it may be broken as pointed out by @K7AAY. I would scan the hard drive sector by sector with something like minitool's partition wizard before using it again. If it does and contains important information you might want to look into recovery options.

Comment: Suggest you make a LiveUSB (one way: https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html but there are many others), boot with it, and see if you can access files on that HDD.